# Add commandline app shortcut

Tags: terminal, command-line

How do I run the app: `~/ngrok` by typing `ngrok`?

I want to add a shortcut to the `~/ngrok` location so that I don't need to know the place where it is when I run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Commands in *nix terminals are stored in various directories throughout the filesystem. The `PATH` variable is a series of colon (`:`) sperated directories that are searched in order to find a desire command. When a command is called, the `PATH` variable is read, and all the paths is contains are checked for the command in question.

You have 2 ways to make your program run without specifying location: either add it to a directory that's already to your `PATH` variable, or add its containing folder to the `PATH` variable.

You can read your current `PATH` variable by running:

`echo $PATH`

And you can edit your `PATH` variable by following a guide such as [this one](http://architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.U2hX1l5mnnY)

P.S. I REALLY strongly discourage keeping files directly within `~/`

Answer (score 0):

You can also make function in Your `~/.bash_profile` file. Simply put this line:

`function ngrok { ~/ngrok; };`

To test it in current terminal window type `source ~/.bash_profile`. New terminal would load this file automatically.